# no play option in visual studio

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to print some text in console of unity but no text gets printed in the console. there is an option of attach to unity and play but even after clicking on it nothing gets displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you not able to see the console printouts in Unity? `Debug.Log("message")` and/or `print("message")` should work. You need to enable your console to view them. Enable it by going to **Window -> General -> Console** in Unity, and enabling debug messages by selecting the message tab on the top left of the console window.

Here is how to enable your console.
[image: Console]

Here is the tab you must select so debug logs or normal print messages are shown in the console log. The tab to the right of the messages are warnings and to the right of that are error messages.
[image: Console Image Settings]

Attaching Visual Studios to Unity when in play mode is only needed when you need to debug your code. It is especially useful when using breakpoints and walking through code to determine complex issues. If you have a debug print message in code, make sure the script is on a `GameObject` that is enabled and active in your scene. Once that is done, just hit the `Play` button in Unity.

Comment: i dont want to debug my code how do i do it

Comment: i just want to play and not debug

Comment: You don't need to hit play on visual studios at all to use Unity. There is a play button in Unity you press. It is in the top middle of the screen

Comment: you misunderstood me i meant i do not wat to debug i just want to run the code and then print out in the console of unity, before this attach to unity messed me up there used to be an option to play or run the program in visual studio and now it is not there.

Comment: You're right I did - sorry about that. You should be able to toggle attached debugger off and the play will come back. Should be under VS -> Debug -> Attach unity debugger -> Untoggle

Comment: there is no option to untoggle it

Comment: @VedPawar Have you tried just clicking the stop button? When attaching the process, the play button should become a stop button. Clicking that will unlink Visual Studios from Unity. I am also very confused why you are trying to run your code outside of Unity. What exactly is your reasoning to do this?

Comment: i am simply following a tutorial in the tutorial they debug.log and then it prints out in therir unity console then why isnt it printing out in mine

Comment: Can you post the tutorial? If you want to see the print out just hit play in Unity. There's almost no reason to run the script outside of unity.

Comment: when i hit play in unity nothing is displayed in the console

Comment: @VedPawar Can you add the script you are trying to print with? The script also needs to be attached to an object in your scene.

Comment: i attached it to a game object and it worked but i still dont get the meaning of attch to unity

Comment: @VedPawar Attach to unity is a different process. Unity will run whatever is in your scripts. Attach to unity will allow you to step through code line by line to debug it with breakpoints. If you are unfamiliar with break points, just google them and you should learn more about them.